# Spring cache using redis does not store data in the cache

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I have a spring boot 2.4.1 application where I configured spring cache with redis.

I have a service with the following method:

```java
    @Cacheable(value = "myCache", key = "'fixed'")
    public Boolean isAuthorized(AuthorizationRequest request){
        return authorizationFeignClient.isAuthorized(request);
    }
```

Every time I call the method I see something like this in the logs:

```
2023.04.07;11:16:30 [reactor-http-epoll-3] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] TRACE o.s.c.interceptor.CacheInterceptor  - Computed cache key 'fixed' for operation Builder[public java.lang.Boolean com.example.AuthorizationClientService.isAuthorized(com.example.model.dto.AuthorizationRequest)] caches=[myCache] | key=''fixed'' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
2023.04.07;11:16:30 [reactor-http-epoll-3] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] TRACE o.s.c.interceptor.CacheInterceptor  - No cache entry for key 'fixed' in cache(s) [myCache]
2023.04.07;11:16:30 [reactor-http-epoll-3] [rootId:  parentId:  eventId: ] TRACE o.s.c.interceptor.CacheInterceptor  - Computed cache key 'fixed' for operation Builder[public java.lang.Boolean com.example.AuthorizationClientService.isAuthorized(com.example.model.dto.AuthorizationRequest)] caches=[myCache] | key=''fixed'' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'
```

And on redis the key is never created.

I've debugged the org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport and can see that the the code that stores the data on the cache gets executed without error, but still nothing.

I don't know what else to try. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try the key without single quotes?

Comment: That doesn't work as it the key property receives a SpEL expression. I tried not defining a key so that it is determined dynamically but the issue is not there, is somewhere else.

Comment: Please share the configuration steps by adding to the question: 1. pom.xml, 2. main application class or equivalent configuration classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a configuration error, I had this on my application.yml

```
spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
    cache-names: myCache
    redis:
      host: localhost
      port: 6379
      time-to-live: 3600
```

And changed it to:

```
spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
    cache-names: myCache
  data:
    redis:
      host: localhost
      port: 6379
```

The weird behavior was that if I stopped redis the application failed so I assumed that the redis connection was correct.

**Edit:**

It looks like the main problem was the `time-to-live` parameter as it must be defined in miliseconds and not in seconds.

Comment: spring.cache.redis.time-to-live: 10s